# Apply generic mask via filter?

Tags: angularjs, masking

I'm currently using ngMask to handle masking for user input.  It works great, but, AFAIK, can only be used on `input` elements.  I now need to mask this same data for display.  For example, in a table, I would hope to display `item.ssn = 123456789` as `123-45-6798`.

What is the best way to do this?  I understand I can make custom filters, but was wondering if there was a generic way to do this for all text.  Like this if you could extend the ngMask functionality...

```
<td><span mask="999-99-9999">{{item.ssn}}</span></td>
```

or as a filter...

```
<td>{{item.ssn|filter:'999-99-9999'}}</td>
```

Comment: _"wondering if there was a generic way to do this for all text"_ Can you give a usage example so we understand clearly?

Comment: Custom filter seems to be the best option here, but you can simplify it greatly using `MaskService` included in `ngMask`

Comment: @Jasen: Sorry.  Updated.

Comment: @BroiSatse: Can you give me an example of how MaskService could be used?

Comment: Maybe I still don't understand correctly... but you can pass the format string into the custom filter `function(input, format)` so that `{ input | filter: format }`

Comment: @Jasen: I don't want to have to create a custom filter every time I need to do this for a different type of data (eg. SSN, phone number, etc).  I want to be able to have a generic implementation - whether it be an existing library or one custom generic filter - that will let me apply a format to a string and have it masked correctly.

Comment: Then vittore's answer works if you pass in the format string. Obviously, you'll need to do the work to parse the string so it does what you want.

Comment: @im1dermike - it is pretty much `var value, mask = MaskService.create(); mask.generateRegex({mask: '99-99-99'}).then(function() {value = mask.getViewValue('123456').withDivisors() });` At this point `value #=> '12-34-56'`. Not posting as an answer as you still need to create a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a filter. You can rely on `MaskService` provided with ngMask:

```
angular.module('myModule').filter('mask', ['MaskService', function(MaskService) {
  return function(text, mask) {
    var result, 
        maskService = MaskService.create(),

    if (!angular.isObject(mask)) {
      mask = { mask: mask }
    }

    maskService.generateRegex(mask).then(function() {
      result = maskService.getViewValue(text).withDivisors() 
    }

    return result;
  }
}])
```

Then:

```
<td>{{item.ssn | mask:'999-99-9999'}}</td>
```

Comment: There are a number of typos with this, but even still, I can only get it to work when I remove the promise and just make it `return function (text, mask) {
            var maskService = MaskService.create();
            maskService.generateRegex({ mask: mask });
            return maskService.getViewValue(text).withDivisors();
        };`

Comment: Promise is pretty much only to handle case when it fails to create a regex, it should be pretty safe to be removed. Sorry for typos, feel free to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`date`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) filter. you pretty much need to implement the same but for strings. You can use [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L350) for reference.

In the simplest case you can just use simple regex replace:

```
angular.module('myModule').filter('ssn', function() {
  return function(text) {
    return (""+text).replace(/(\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/, '$1-$2-$3');
 }
})

<td>{{item.ssn|ssn}}</td>
```

Comment: I understand how I can make a custom filter.  My goal is to make something generic.

Comment: Then just pass in the format string `function(text, format)`

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Follow.

https://github.com/alairjt/displayMask

```
<span>{{'01234567890' | mask:'999.999.999-99'}}</span>
```

//012.345.678-90

Comment: Consider explaining in words what you did to achieve the result you put forth. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

Just use AngularJS

```
{{youdate | date : "dd.MM.y"}}
```

reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: If you could expand upon your explnaation it would be good as link only answers are really frowned upon and if that link breaks the bulk of your answer is lost